# How to stop Flying Saucer (xhtmlrender) PDFs showing border around hyperlinks on MacOS X?

Tags: java, macos, pdf, pdf-generation, flying-saucer

I am using Flying Saucer (xhtmlrenderer) to create a PDF that contains a hyperlink. When the PDF is viewed in Adobe Reader it looks as expected, but when viewed in Preview.app on the mac it displays a thin black border around the hyperlink.

How do I get Flying Saucer to render the PDF such that this border is not displayed?

From some further investigation, I have seen this problem is also exhibited in

- Mac version of Acrobat Reader

But does not occur in

- Evince on ubuntu
- Adobe Reader on ubuntu
- Acrobat Reader on windows

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like this is an unresolved bug in xhtmlrenderer - https://xhtmlrenderer.dev.java.net/issues/show_bug.cgi?id=265